# rsyslogd - how to discard repeats of alarm "X" unless alarm "Y" happens in-between (preserve context)

Tags: snmp, rsyslog

I have an interface which when disconnected spits out alarms every 60 seconds.

`ERROR: Connection FOO is DOWN`

My rsyslogd is spamming the downstream SNMP agents.  To avoid that, I want to send only on alarm when the connection goes DOWN.  Easy enough you might say, just use action.execOnlyOnceEveryInterval.

But the trick is that once the connection comes back up...

`NOTICE: Connection FOO is UP.`

...I want to reset that state, so that as soon as it goes down again subsequently I immediately log/relay the re-occurrence of the DOWN state.

I see Local Variables in RainerScript, but that's no use.  I need Global variables to retain state between messages.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 7.5.6 or later, you can use mmsequence as follows.

```
module(load="mmsequence")
if ($programname == "myprog") and ($msg contains "Bad Conn1")
then {
    action(
        type="mmsequence"
        mode="key"
        key="connection1"
        step="1"
        var="$!counter1"
    )
    if ($!counter1 > 1) then stop;
}
if ($programname == "myprog") and ($msg contains "Good Conn1")
then {
    action(
        type="mmsequence"
        mode="key"
        key="connection1"
        step="1"
        to="1"
        var="$!counter1"
    )
}
```

Note that mmsequence is marked as "deprecated" in rsyslog v8.  The documentation states that you should use "global variables" instead.  However, searching the documentation for global variables gives no information about how you can use these mythical "global variables".